# Pointer to a child class

Tags: c++

I have a class which needs a pointer to a child class :

```
class A
{
    protected :
        B *pB;
}

class B : public A
{

}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Put a forward declaration of `class B` before the class `A` definition. But having a base class know about derived types is not a great design.

Comment: You surely meant `class B : public A`?

Comment: In order for anything in your question to make any sense at all, I guess "class A : public B" should actually be "class B : public A".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a forward declaration at the beginning:

```
class B;

class A
{
    protected :
    B *pB;
}

class A : public B
{

}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be class B : public A?

Answer (score 3):

You need to forward declare B otherwise the compiler doesn't know B exists if it is listened after A.

```
class B;

class A
{
    protected :
        B *pB;
}

class A : public B
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forward declare `class B` and it should be `class   B: public A`, not the reverse.
i.e.

```
class B;
class A
{
  protected:
    B *pB;
}

class B: public A
{

}
```